# Use moveRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to find a code sample that shows how to handle moving/rearranging cells in a tableView.

For removal of Core data I use the code that is written below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)

{

    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyBase"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];


    NSArray *empArray=[self.objectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    if ([empArray count] > 0){
        Moneybox *employee = [empArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.objectContext deleteObject:employee];
        [self.objectContext save:nil];

    }

    [self buscarContactoExistente];
    [myTable reloadData];

}

}
```

How do I make

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
```

in the same style?

Comment: What sortDescription do you use on the FetchRequest, used for populating your table? You need to make changes to your data, that will reflect the reordering of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath 
{
    Moneybox *employee = [empArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [empArray removeObject: employee];
    [empArray insertObject:employee atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: no visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeObject'

Comment: use NSMutableArray. change your empArray as NSMutableArray instead of NSArray

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_PFArray removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e2eda0'

Comment: -[_PFArray removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e2eda0

Comment: use your source array. source array should be NSMutableArray.

Comment: Are you using _PFArray in numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: I'am use NSMutableArray. My program was compiled. But when the movement of the error appears. I wrote them up.

Comment: my numberOfRowsInSection return [self.contactosAnadidos count];

Comment: please check this sample project, http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.in/2010/12/how-to-drag-or-move-cell-in-uitableview.html

Comment: You need to give this array self.contactosAnadidos.

Comment: NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Moneybox"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
    
    NSError* error;
    self.contactosAnadidos = [self.objectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

Comment: Well now I can move elimenty array. Now how do I keep it in core data?